# mysql 0000-00-00 update error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1292

I am trying to update a my date field to null instead of 0000-00-00, but I errors.

```
 ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'rel_date' at row 1
```

However I can update the records individually?

```
 update table set rel_date = NULL where id = 12;
```

But if I try

```
update table set rel_date = NULL where rel_date like '%0000%'
or
update table set rel_date = NULL where rel_date = '0000-00-00'
I get ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'rel_date' at row 1
```

schema

```
id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| document_id   | varchar(40)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                   |
| revision_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Comment: Show your database schema. The column probably is not nullable.

Comment: | revision_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

Comment: Also check `SELECT @@SQL_MODE`. Recent MySQL versions default to a `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode.

Comment: You really don't want zero dates in your database, so MySQL is just looking out for you here. If you need to purge bad data, try switching to `VARCHAR(255)`, cleaning it, then flipping back to `DATE`.

Comment: Yes the NO_ZERO_DATE is set.  Do i just set sql_mode session to nothing.  Then run my update.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE',''));
```

Run update command. 
close instance of mysql or probably add back to current session.

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',NO_ZERO_DATE'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If you have a minimum valid date in your table, suppose it is '1950-01-01', then you could do:

```
update table set rel_date = NULL where rel_date < '1950-01-01'
```

Comment: thank you ..you saved my life... instead of `rel_date='0000-00-00'`, i use this `rel_date < '0001-01-01'`...and it's working